# Notificar atualização de uma resposta negativada

Tags: debate, status-recusado, voto-contra

[**Essa resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/36817/13412) me levantou uma *sugestão* que queria compartilhar. Eu não negativei a resposta, mas avisei com um comentário explicando que aos meus olhos ela contém erro. No momento ela está `-1 / +3`, foi corrigida enquanto eu criava essa questão.

---

Se uma resposta negativada por não fornece uma solução para um problema for atualizada e se tornar correta, quem negativou pode acabar esquecendo de acompanhar. Nem sempre são atualizadas em tempo, ou nem sempre quem vota pode acompanhar todas as respostas votadas. Acredito que algumas respostas acabam sendo esquecidas e o *down-vote* não é desfeito mesmo quando corrigida, tornando um voto injusto ou descuidado.

Diante disso, não seria interessante gerar uma notificação para casos em que a resposta negativada sofra alteração?

> A resposta que você negativou foi alterada, considere se ainda merece seu voto.

---

Dessa forma poderia evitar a necessidade de se acompanhar individualmente todas as questões que foram negativadas e possivelmente corrigir o voto.

Comment: Isso eu acho bem interessante. Eu costumo revisar meus downvotes, mas sei que nem todo mundo o faz, e mesmo eu e os que tem hábito de repassar as perguntas podem esquecer algum  negativo indevido perdido por aí.

Comment: @Papa acho uma ótima ideia!

Comment: É uma ideia muito boa, entretanto já foi feito um feature-request no Metão sobre o assunto e foi declinado. Veja: [Allow an edit to notify downvoters: “I think I've fixed the issue now - please check”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751/229289)

Comment: @Math o detalhe que eu achei curioso foi o autor do pedido.

Comment: @brasofilo, você que é o cara dos experimentos, não tem como fazer uma rotina pra isso para rodar uma query?

Answer (score 7):

Eu acho que alertar para os erros é sempre a atitude positiva. Também acho que quem vota negativo sem alertar para o erro, não está muito interessado na em melhorar a qualidade da resposta.

Outro aspeto importante, é o tipo de erro. Se for um erro de digitação ou notória falta de atenção de quem dá a resposta ainda vale a pena tentar salvar. Nesta situação a edição é uma ferramenta fantástica.

Agora se a resposta estiver estruturalmente errada, não vejo muito o que se possa fazer.

Mas de qualquer forma, acho que pode ser uma boa ideia e um incentivo para um maior empenho em corrigir as respostas.

Comment: Uma simples notificaçãozinha mostrando que a resposta foi editada já mostra que vale conferir o empenho, que na maioria dos casos é corrigindo algum deslize.

Comment: Quem vota negativo sem comentar pode estar querendo somente ajudar a "rankear" os conteúdos do site. Eu acho válido (sei que muitos discordam e respeito a opinião contrária).

Comment: Outra leitura que transfere a responsabilidade para o autor da resposta: *"Puxa, me votaram negativamente sem deixar comentário, vou pesquisar o que posso melhorar (técnica e esteticamente)"*.

Answer (score 0):

Tenho outro exemplo concreto: [Por que usar SELECT * FROM tabela é ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21583/por-que-usar-select-from-tabela-%C3%A9-ruim/22835#22835)

Na resposta do @Alexei, a primeira versão que ele postou recebeu diversos negativos incluindo um meu.

Alguns dias depois a resposta foi editada e recebeu positivos.

Eu fiquei confuso porque um ponto é debitado de quem negativa também.
Então, se a resposta é alterada, não deveria anular os negativos ou algo do tipo?
Porque os negativos deixam, em partes, de serem "válidos". Quem votou negativo não recebe seus pontos de volta ou não tem "chance" de corrigir já que a resposta foi modificada?

Acho que é injusto para aqueles que votaram negativo, debitando de suas pontuações pois o autor da resposta teve "chance" de corrigir e ficar positivo e os que votaram, não.

Comment: Mas nem sempre uma resposta editada corresponde à correção de um erro. Nesse caso alguém que respondeu e levou `-3` basta editar umas letras e zerar a pontuação, mas o erro continuaria.

Comment: Depois que a resposta foi modificada, você pode voltar nela e retirar seu -1, aí recebe o ponto de volta.

Comment: Aí que está... como vc vai saber que, uma resposta na qual vc negativou, foi alterada? No meu caso eu percebi porque tenho poucos posts e estava de certa forma acompanhando o post acima específico. Mas imagine se tivesse uns mil posts.
Não vou checar 1 por 1 todos os dias 24 horas por dia.

De qualquer forma, obrigado pela dica.. As vezes fico até com medo de apertar em qualquer botão nesse site porque sempre tem alguma surpresa te negativando por qualquer coisa.. rsrsrs

Comment: Daniel, tem vezes que, estando a toa sem nada pra fazer, vou na tab de reputação no meu perfil e vou catando cada `-1` pra ver se posso reverter o voto.

Comment: Aí que está² haha. Nem todos tem esse tempo a toa brother. Cada um tem seu tempo e usa como quer, mas não posso dispor de meu tempo vago para ficar aqui no site. Tenho uma vida para viver fora da web, filhos, esposa, essas coisas. Claro, não querendo ofender a quem usa o tempo vago no site, pois cada um faz o que bem entende. Mas nem todos usam o tempo vago para "dedicar-se" ao site. Eu tenho poucos posts mas se eu tivesse uns mil posts e depois de 1 ano tem uns posts de 1 anos atrás que foi negativado hoje, quer dizer que tenho que ficar o tempo todo consultando todos os meus posts? Inviável.